# Translate field name in .po file Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Given the following couple of fields in an Odoo 10 model which inherits product.template:

```
label_code = fields.Text(string='Code', readonly=True)
label_type_id = fields.Many2one('label_type', string='Type', required=False)
```

Which would be the right syntax to translate them in the .PO? 
I have tried:

```
#. module: my_module
#: model:product.template,name:my_module.label_form
msgid "Code"
msgstr "Código"

#. module: my_module
#: model:product.template,name:my_module.label_form
msgid "Type"
msgstr "Tipo"
```

where label_form is the template id where I need the translation